# Why straight-forward question is getting close votes for being "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Why is straight-forward question getting close votes for being "too broad"?

[Why did Spielberg use fictional characters (informants Louis and Papa) in Munich](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74908/why-did-spielberg-use-fictional-characters-informants-louis-and-papa-in-munich)

> **too broad** - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any -
>   are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format''

I have one question, it is rather straightforward - **Why Spielberg used fictional characters in based on true story movie, while real facts were known and could have been used instead?** To me it seems people have used TL:DR approach here. I have given every piece of information I know in the matter and with my limited capabilities in English language tried to put into simple question. I have given background to movie, so one who has not seen it still may understand the question asked. Secondly I explain what I am asking and why am I asking it. Because it just seems absurd why use fictional characters in two leading roles in movie which states everywhere else it is based on real facts - a book - where there is no fact or character similar to one portrayed in the movie.

I do admit, one may find it has many possible answers - but that would be an opinion. And as I state (as well this site demands) I am looking answer with a source, not opinion based theories. The question is clear in manner and looks for a reason, which can be answered in short manner. The only problem I face is that there many not be valid source for this - I have looked for hours, done my fair share of homework, and have not come to any possible answers yet or just not found one. I hope for the second part so I could find the reason or someone could lead me there - a reason for asking a question. Its rather important part in the book and seems bizarre why it has been distorted to that extent.

I do not see what I have done wrong here, except maybe I wrote a little too long question. But broad, hell no! In addition I do not see any comments why there is vote to close.

Comment: It got one close vote and 3 leave open vote, nothing much to worry here.